# How to use plugins in NativesScrip Sidekick?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm actually having a terrible time learning `Nativescript`.

I've mentioned this in my previous questions and I will say it here again.

This platform and its Doc is an absolute mess. The only and the only reason that i am insisting to learn it is because of its "*Native*" features. and thats it.

That being said, I'm using sidekick to develop my app.

I can find and install the plugins in sidekick.

However, most if not all of the plugins have an `import xxxx` code.

for example: https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet#readme

I don't understand how to use the given **usage code** in my app after I've installed the plugin!

And i cannot find any information about this anywhere on google or stackoverflow! not even on their own website!

Could someone please point me in a right direction?

**EDIT:**

I know how to install plugins in sidekick etc. however, most plugins use `import` instead of `require(xxxx)`... and in sidekick, you can only use `require(xxx)`. and that is where my confusion is! as an example, look at the plugin i provided above in my question.

Comment: someone from Telerik didn't like the brutal honesty lol.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you find it so difficult, I hope it's all self explanatory if you open Sidekick app.

[image: Plugin Management on {N} Sidekick]

Personally I like to stay with command line than using Sidekick. Here are the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/plugins) explains how you would install & use a plugin from command line. You also have Sidekick specific guidelines [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/configure-app/plugins-management).

If you are familiar with JavaScript and had used NPM packages, you must have already known NPM packages are pices of code / library which you can import and use in your project. Every plugin already demonstrates the usage in their docs (most times in ReadMe).

For example, [NativeScript Firebase Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#start-up-wiring)

```
var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

firebase.init({
  // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
  // see their respective docs.
}).then(
    function () {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);
```

**Edit:**

All the documentations assumes you are familiar with basics of JavaScript. 
`import` is more modern way of writing where `require` is traditional one. Both syntaxes work with Sidekick. Sidekick is just a GUI tool, it doesn't alter the capabilities of your programming language.

There is also TypeScript / Babel (JavaScript compilers) which allows you to use modern syntaxes, during compilation, the code will be converted to your desired version of JavaScript.

If you haven't used JavaScript in the past, I would recommend you to learn the basics so the {N} documentations will become much more familiar to you.

Comment: You are deflecting my question. on the firebase plugin that you've included in your answer, there is clearly a code example that has `var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");`. However, in my question, I provided another plugin that doesn't use `require(xxxx)` function and instead uses `import` and that is where my confusion is. as far as I know, you cannot use `import` in sidekick and you need to use `require(xxxx)`!

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the above question. please read the question again.